# How to make range bar graphs in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

[range bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ywu3.png)
How can I made a graph like what is shown in the image using gnuplot?
I want a bar graph where each bar has a maximum and minimum value.
Is this possible in gnuplot?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use e.g.  `boxxyerrorbars` plotting style for that

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `boxxyerrorbars` style.

For example, given a datafile `test.dat` with content

```
#ymin  ymax
  2     4
  3     6
  1     4
  2     3
```

the gnuplot commands

```
boxwidth = 0.5
set style fill solid
set yrange [0:8]
plot "test.dat" u 0:(($1+$2)/2.):(boxwidth/2.):(($2-$1)/2.) w boxxyerrorbars
```

give

[image]