# How can I make a bar graph displaying y-min and y-max data along with custom colors for each bar?

Tags: bar-chart, gnuplot

I would like to make a bar graph that displays each bar as the bottom of the bar being y-min and the top of the bar being y-max. In addition I'd like each bar to have its own color fill and custom tics where xtic(1). Thank you

Similar to this below:

[How to make range bar graphs in gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46188086/how-to-make-range-bar-graphs-in-gnuplot)

ex.

```
#number #y-min #y-max #rgb
1        2      5      1
2        2.5    5.4    2
3        4      6      3
4        4.3    7      4
```

Comment: You want this in gnuplot? Then you better tag it with `gnuplot`. What have you tried so far? Have you checked the manual and the gnuplot homepage? What is your script so far? What is your graph output?

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out and posted the script in the event someone else needs it. is that fine? @theozh

Comment: If you have found a solution please answer your own question with an answer instead of editing the question. It will be not a question anymore. You can (actually should) accept your own answer if you think it is the best of the existing answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing in case someone else needs it

```
set termoption font ",22"
boxwidth = 0.5
set style fill solid
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
set xtics font "{/:Bold,22}"
set ytics font "{/:Bold,22}"
set xlabel "Structure"
set xlabel  font "{/:Bold,30}"
set ylabel "Potential (V vs. RHE)"
set ylabel  font "{/:Bold,30}"
set xrange [-1:4.5]
set yrange [0:7]
set arrow from -1,2.5 to 4.5,2.5 nohead lc rgb 'black' dt 3
plot 'poten-range-plot' u 0:(($2+$3)/2.):(boxwidth/2.):(($3-$2)/2.):4:xtic(1) w boxxyerrorbars notitle lw 3 lc variable, 1/0 t "Pt (111)" lt 1 lc rgb 'black'
```